# How to pass parent component state data to the child component in variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a parent component(index.js) which has a state `x:[]` and state contains the data `[{…}, {…}, {…}]` & I have a child component(child.jsx), in child component(child.jsx) i want to save the parent component data `[{…}, {…}, {…}]` in a variable in child component.

Parent component(index.js)

```
//here i have more imports
import Child from "./child"

export default class Index extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  
            x: [],  
        };
    }

//some functions

render() {

    const { x } = this.state;
    console.log(x, "this is the data")
        // x contains data [{…}, {…}, {…}]

          return (
           <div className="class">                                           
                  <Autocomplete x={this.state.x} />
               </div>
            }
}
```

Child component(child.jsx)

```
//here i have imports

const suggestions =  here i want x data from the parent component;

//some functions

export default function Child(props) {
 return (
    <div className="material">
      <div className={classes.root}   
        <Autosuggest
          {...props.x}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}
```

Mainly getting undefined error when i try to pass some props.

expected result:

```
"x data from the parent component" 
const suggestions = [{…}, {…}, {…}];
```

Comment: You import Child in Parent but then never do anything with it, is some code missing?

Comment: Instead of `<Autocomplete x={this.state.x} />`, do you mean `<Child x={this.state.x} />`.

Comment: no, this is the material.ui component.

Answer (score 0):

You put suggestions outside the scope of the functional component, so you can't access props.
 You need to move suggestions inside Child:

```
export default function Child(props) {

const suggestions =  props.x;

 return (
    <div className="material">
      <div className={classes.root}   
        <Autosuggest
          {...props.x}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}
```

I assumed you render Child component from Parent component, and gave him the prop x.

Comment: thanks,when i am trying your approach  let suggestions = props.x;  console.log(suggestions, "this is the suggestion");   then the suggestion is undefined, not getting the data.

Comment: did you render Child component from Index component?

Answer (score 0):

you can not access props for any component outside its scope so props send to child is only accessible inside child component not in all file because there may be more than one child component in the same file.

```
Either use let like this: 


    let suggestions;
    //some functions

    export default function Child(props) {
    suggestions = props.x;
     return (
        <div className="material">
          <div className={classes.root}   
            <Autosuggest
              {...props.x}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      );

    }


Or


export default function Child(props) {

const suggestions = props.x;
 return (
    <div className="material">
      <div className={classes.root}   
        <Autosuggest
          {...props.x}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your data (props) from parent to current component, then pass it to child again, or you can simply use context system
[Read about context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components

I hope you get the idea and works for you